# URL query parameters returns null even when parameter is seted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url

I have a react app with react router and dynamic URL. And i also have 2 GET parameters like `/?name=something&date=2021` and while name parameter works fine `date` for some reason always returns null.
I set parameters in form with onSubmit

```
function submitAction(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  props.onChange(search, selectedDate);
  const currUrl = new URL(window.location.href);
  currUrl.searchParams.set("date", format(selectedDate, "yyyy"));
  currUrl.searchParams.set("name", search);
  window.history.pushState({}, "", currUrl);
  setSearch("");
}
```

And get parameters with `useEffect()` react hook

```
  useEffect(() => {
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.href);
const date = params.get("date");
const name = params.get("name");
console.log(name);
console.log(date);  //this always returns null
if (name) {
  setFilter(name);
}
if (date) {
  setDate(new Date(date));
}}, []);
```

So my query string changes and it works, but my second URL parameter isn't working
Query string looks like `http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F%3Fdate=2018&name=`

Comment: Put a `console.log(selectedDate);` in submitAction to test the value. Also, what is the code of the `format` function?

Comment: ```console.log(selectedDate)``` returns ```Date Tue Jun 05 2018 11:38:33 GMT+0300```

Comment: ```format``` is a function from date-fns package that parse ```Date()``` object to needed format

Comment: What does `console.log(format(selectedDate, 'yyyy'));` output?

Comment: for ```Date Tue Jun 05 2018 11:38:33 GMT+0300``` ```console.log(format(selectedDate, 'yyyy'))``` returns 2018

Comment: URL is changing but I still can't get date parameter after refreshing page. And name works just as intended. I don't understand why.
Right now my URL is ```http://localhost:3000/?date=2018&name=``` .And while ```console.log(name)``` in ```useEffect()``` returns empty string ```date``` returns null

Comment: The URLSearchParams constructor does not parse full URLs, only the query string portion. I suspect this is where the issue is.

Comment: In my case I need only query strings to set default state of search filter with url parameters. Other part of routing depends on react-router

Comment: The point is you are passing `window.location.href`, which is a full URL, in the `URLSearchParams` constructor. It doesn't parse full URLs, so this is likely what is causing your issue.

Comment: You can use `window.location.search` in the `URLSearchParams` constructor to get the correct details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URLSearchParams constructor does not parse a full URL, only the query string.

Change

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.href);
```

To

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
```